# Grep after and before lines of last Match

Tags: search, grep, match, tail

I am searching through few logs and I want to grep the last match along with it's above and below few lines.

`grep -A10 -B10  "searchString" my.log` will print all the matches with after and before 10 lines
`grep "searchString" my.log | tail -n 1` will print the last match.

I want to combine both and get the after and before 10 lines of last match.

Comment: Can't you just do `grep -A10 -B10  "searchString" my.log | tail -n 21` and claim `blackjack`?

Comment: `-A10 -B10` is the same as `-C10` if your `grep` supports it.

Comment: @BroSlow, that prints last 21 matches not the 20 lines before/after last match

Comment: @Jotne, I am aware of that. But I do change A and B quite frequently depends on my case

Comment: @Reddy So you don't want the `10 lines preceding the last match + the last match + 10 lines after the last match` = 21?

Comment: @Reddy Or are you saying your `grep` mixes the order of the matches and the associated lines somehow? Because otherwise without the tail, it should just print `line1...line10 match1 line1...line10 line1...line10 match2 line1...line10, etc...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like to have all in one command, try this `awk`

```
awk '/search/ {f=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {while(i++<NR) if (i>f-3 && i<f+3) print a[i]}' file
```

How it works:

```
awk '
/search/ {                      # Is pattern found
    f=NR}                       # yes, store the line number (it will then store only the last when all is run
    {
    a[NR]=$0}                   # Save all lines in an array "a"
END {
    while(i++<NR)               # Run trough all lines once more
        if (i>f-3 && i<f+3)     # If line number is +/- 2 compare to last found pattern, then 
            print a[i]          # Printe the line from the array "a"
    }' file                     # read the file
```

A more flexible solution to handle `before` and `after`

```
awk '/fem/ {f=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {while(i++<NR) if (i>=f-before && i<=f+after) print a[i]}' before=2 after=2 file
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the question, you can just `tail` the last 21 lines

```
 grep -A10 -B10  "searchString" my.log | tail -n 21
```

i.e.

```
> for i in {1..10}; do echo $i >> example; done; \
echo foo >> example; \
for i in {1..10}; do echo $i >> example; done; \
for i in {A..Z}; do echo $i >> example; done; \
for i in {a..j}; do echo $i >> example; done; \
echo foo >> example; \
for i in {k..z}; do echo $i >> example; done
> grep -A10 -B10  foo example | tail -n 21
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
foo
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
tac yourfile.log | grep -m1 -A2 -B2 'search' | tac
```